# How to open pop-up from link button and close it using button inside the pop-up?

Tags: wpf

I have main window, containing grid with different user controls. Each control is defined in separate Xaml. Then in MainWindow.xaml i match all particles of my main window.

One of my userControls is a menu, containing buttons. 
i want to call popup after clicking some button in menu. Popup will contain some text, buttons and will overlay the main window.
So the question is how to call pop-up from menu-button and close it from button located on pop-up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a togglebutton in your menu, then bind the IsOpen property of the Popup to the IsChecked property of the togglebutton.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggle" Content="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="78,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=toggle, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Height="299" Width="269">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=toggle, Path=IsChecked}" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

Change StaysOpen back to True (the default) if you don't want the popup to go away when you click off it. In this situation, the togglebutton inside the popup will look a bit strange by default, but you can style it to look better.

If not all your code is in the same Xaml file, instead of binding by ElementName, you can bind them all to a boolean property in your viewmodel.